# Dart Unit Test - Always passing

Tags: dart, dart-async, dart-unittest

All,

Here is a unit test for checking the size of a collection

```dart
main() {
  test("Resource Manager Image Load", () {
    ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager();
    int WRONG_SIZE = 1000000;

    rm.loadImageManifest("data/rm/test_images.yaml").then((_){
      print("Length="+ rm.images.length.toString()); // PRINTS '6' - WHICH IS CORRECT
      expect(rm.images, hasLength(WRONG_SIZE));
    });
  });
}
```

I am running this from a browser (client-side Dart libraries are in use) and it ALWAYS passes, no matter what the value of WRONG_SIZE.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such simple cases you can just return the future. The unit test framework recognizes it and waits for the future to complete. This also works for `setUp`/`tearDown`.

```dart
main() {
  test("Resource Manager Image Load", () {
    ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager();
    int WRONG_SIZE = 1000000;

    return rm.loadImageManifest("data/rm/test_images.yaml").then((_) {
    //^^^^
      print("Length="+ rm.images.length.toString()); // PRINTS '6' - WHICH IS CORRECT
      expect(rm.images, hasLength(WRONG_SIZE));
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Didn't realise that; much better!

Comment: I did exactly this - except I did not use the 'return rm....'. Now its working. Thx. I do find this 'async everywhere' approach with Dart takes some getting used to...

Comment: Yeah, that's nice. What did you do instead?

Comment: Exactly as your function...just no 'return' statement ;-)

Comment: Seems I misunderstood your comment ;-). Yeah - just the return was missing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your code returns a `Future`, and your test completes before the code in the Future has finished, so there's nothing to cause it to fail.

Check out the [Asynchronous Tests](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-unit-tests/#asynchronous-tests) section on the Dart site. There are methods like `expectAsync` that allow the future to be passed to the test framework so that it can wait for them to complete and handle the result correctly.

Here's an example (note the `expect` call is now inside the function passed to `expectAsync`)

```dart
test('callback is executed once', () {
  // wrap the callback of an asynchronous call with [expectAsync] if
  // the callback takes 0 arguments...
  var timer = Timer.run(expectAsync(() {
    int x = 2 + 3;
    expect(x, equals(5));
  }));
});
```